# Establishing an SSH connection in a CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssh

Recently I came across this library, which allows me to connect via `ssh` to a remote machine. ( this case, a fake `123.45.67.890`. The library is
[shukydvir](https://bitbucket.org/shukydvir/codeigniter-ssh2-library/overview).

I followed the instructions given in the `overview` tab, however, as shown below:

```
public function deploy_test()
{
    $params = array( 
                'hostname' => "123.45.67.890",
                'port' => 23,
                'username' => "username",
                'password' => "password"
                );

    if(!($con = $this->ssh->connect($params))) {
        echo json_encode("fail: unable to establish connection\n");
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode("helloworld");
    }
}
```

when what I got back in the webpage is:

```
fail: unable to establish connection
```

Thus, tired of that, I installed `ssh2` library, and I restated my server:

```
public function deploy_test() {
    $connection = ssh2_connect("123.45.67.890", 23);

    if(!$connection) {
       echo json_encode('Connection failed');
    }

    ssh2_auth_password($connection, "username", "password");
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "ls -l");
    stream_get_blocking($stream, true);
    $output = "";
    while($line = fgets($stream)) {
        $output .= $line;
    }
    echo json_encode($line);
}
```

The results are not encouraging:

```
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to 123.45.67.890 on port 23</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/automation.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 70</p>
```

However, when I execute the same script from my `test.php` file, I get:

```
02/13/2013  10:41 PM              .
02/13/2013  10:41 PM              ..
02/13/2013  10:41 PM               952 FreeSSHd.lnk
               1 File(s)            952 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  55,343,263,744 bytes free
```

The other server has `freSSHD` installed, and it's ready to do connections. I have tried everything I can. could someone please help me?

Comment: So you're saying it works from your `test.php` file but not when you run the same code from a CodeIgniter controller?

Comment: @MattB. That's exactly what I'm saying ... can you believe it?

Comment: Can you create a new controller that only contains the `deploy_test()` method, and in case you were using a custom controller base class, have it inherit from `CI_Controller` instead? Then post the full code for the test controller on gist.github.com or pastebin. Maybe it will help us isolate the issue.

Comment: Actually that would basically be what you already posted here so I created it myself just to be clear: https://gist.github.com/mbrowne/5101004. When you run it from this test controller, it doesn't work?

Comment: @MattB. I will do it right now, and post the answer on that `gist` you've created.

Comment: @MattB. I did what you had suggested, and the outcome was the same :-(

Comment: Try putting the code at both the top and bottom of CodeIgniter's index.php. If it doesn't even work when placed at the top of index.php then there must be some small difference in the code even if you thought you copied and pasted it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter-SSH2 Library is using php' native function ssh2_connect() which is sftp based secure shell login and connects basically to port 22. try changing your port:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect("123.45.67.890", 22);
```

Comment: yes but still depends on which port the domain/ip is set to handle ssh connections.

Comment: @PinoyPal My `freeSSHD` is set to receive connections through port `23`. However, what bugs me the most is why when I execute `test.php` it works ...